# Keras CNN how can i reduce gpu memory usage with large image sizes?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a cnn-lstm model, my sample image sizes are 640x640.

I have a GTX 1080 ti 11GB.

I am using Keras with tensorflow backend.

Here is the model.

```
img_input_1 = Input(shape=(1, n_width, n_height, n_channels))

conv_1 = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(96, (11,11), activation='relu', padding='same'))(img_input_1)

pool_1 = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((3,3)))(conv_1)

conv_2 = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (11,11), activation='relu', padding='same'))(pool_1)

flat_1 = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(conv_2)

dense_1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))(flat_1)

drop_1 = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5))(dense_1)

lstm_1 = LSTM(17, activation='linear')(drop_1)

dense_2 = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(lstm_1)

dense_output_2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_2)

model = Model(inputs=img_input_1, outputs=dense_output_2)

op = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.001)

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=op, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=3, batch_size=1)
```

Right now using this model i can only use the training data when the images are resized to 60x60, any larger and i run out of GPU memory.

I want to use the largest possible size as i want to retain as much discriminatory information as possible. (The y labels will be mouse screen coordinates between 0 - 640)

Among many others, i found this answer:
https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3938/how-to-handle-images-of-large-sizes-in-cnn

Though i am not sure how i can "restrict your CNN" or "stream your data in each epoch" or if these would help.

How can i reduce the amount of memory used so i can increase the image sizes?

Is it possible to sacrifice training time/computation speed in favor of higher resolution data whilst retaining model effectiveness?

Note: The above model is not final, just a basic outlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Dense` layer is probably blowing up the training. To give some context, let's assume you are using the `640x640x3` image size. And let's forget about the `LSTM` layer as well and pretend this is a non time-series task (and of course, being a time-series problem complexity becomes worse).

Here are the output sizes.

- `Conv1` -> `640x640x96`
- `Maxpool1` -> `210x210x96` (appx)
- `Conv2` -> `210x210x128`

Now comes the bottleneck. You are then `flatten()`-ing the output and sending it to a `Dense` layer. This dense layer has `210x210x128x4096` parameters (which is `23,121,100,800`). Assuming `32-bit` precision, your dense layer will take around ~86GB (I hope my calculations are correct, but I guarantee you that is not a small number).

So you got few options.

- First and most obvious, reduce your `Dense` layer size.
- Reduce the size of the minibatches
- Reduce the channel depth of the `Conv` layers.
- And you might want to think if you really want the input to be `640x640x3`. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might be able to do that with a smaller image.

Comment: Thanks, reducing the dense layer helped abit, i'm trying to predict x, y coordinates within 640x 640 (and hopefully larger) bounds to move the mouse to on screen. To clarify, by channel depth do you mean the color channels of the images?

Comment: Yes I think you are correct. But to reiterate by channel depth, I mean the first argument of your conv layers (i.e. channel depth of the conv layers outputs)